# Failure Rate of Contraception over n years

Tags: probability

According to [multiple](http://www.guttmacher.org/pubs/fb_contr_use.html) [sources](http://www.cdc.gov/reproductivehealth/unintendedpregnancy/contraception.htm), the probability that, after one year of typical use, a woman who uses male condoms will get pregnant is $18\%$. Presumably, this assumes that the woman will have sex at an average frequency, but I found it hard to find information about this.

What's surprising is that I calculated the probability of unintended pregnancy over four years using male condoms to be very close to $55\%$. I calculated this by noting that, in order not to be pregnant after four years, contraception has to be successful $4$ times. In other words, the probability of successful contraception over four years is $(1 - .18)^4 = .4521$. Therefore, the probability of contraception failing and producing a pregnancy sometime during those four years is $54.79\%$.

Is this technique sound?

Comment: This is the method used by The New York Times in [this infographic titled "How Likely Is It That Birth Control Could Let You Down?"](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2014/09/14/sunday-review/unplanned-pregnancies.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (1-p)^n formula and/or usage of an exponential decay or poisson rate involves assumption of IID - independent, identically distributed repetitions.

But what if there are variations of probability among users of contraception?  This could occur through poor technique, or misreporting in the survey (yes, every time... not).

So, there could be subgroups that have yearly pregnancy probabilities other than 18%.  Grouping them all and averaging, you get 18% for one year.  But in each of these subgroups the percentage is different and because of the exponential would evolve quite differently over longer time periods.

Actually modelling the probability of a particular couple would seem to be more complex than this, even if we assumed groupings... since we are combining men of type A,B,C,D,... with women of type W,X,Y,Z,... and would have NxM different combinations ... perhaps too complex to be a model in previous studies.

Comment: I see! So you mean that the total average rate of unplanned pregnancies over longer time periods would evolve differently depending on variations between subgroups? Would you expect the evolution over longer time periods to be significantly different than using the technique I used (say, greater than 10 percentage points)?

Comment: What it comes down to is whether it is reasonable to assume that someone who has "typical use" for one year is likely to continue to have "typical use" for three more years.  For those for whom this is true, your calculation is almost correct.  But if an individual's patterns of condom use tend to change a lot over time, it may well be that the "four years of typical use" statistic doesn't actually reflect any typical behavior.

Comment: The reason for my use of "almost" in the above comment is that there may also be fertility factors at play, independent of condom use.  Suppose, for argument's sake, that 1% of couples are completely unable to conceive.  Your model, and any such exponential decay model, will find that given enough time, the pregnancy rate will reach 100%.  But if 1% of couples will never conceive, then the true limiting value is actually 99%.